# Calculating the number of weeks between two dates given a specific year in R

Tags: date, rounding

I have some data of several columns, the first two are:

```
begin_date end_date
2012-03-24 2012-04-10
2012-11-14 2013-01-10
2012-07-15 2013-07-15
2013-01-24 2013-07-30
```

I want to calculate the number of weeks in 2013 during these two dates for each row and then round up when necessary.

For example the first row would obviously result in 0.

The second row would result in 2 weeks as 10 days round up to 2 weeks.
etc

Here is the sample code:

```
x <- data.frame(start_date=factor(c("2012-03-24", "2012-11-14", "2012-07-15", "2013-01-24")), 
                end_date=factor(c("2012-04-10", "2013-01-10", "2013-07-15", "2013-07-30")))
x$start_date <-as.Date(x$start_date)
x$end_date <- as.Date(x$end_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  survey <- data.frame(date=c("2012-03-24","2012-04-10"),tx_start=c("2012-11-14","2013-01-10"))

survey$date_diff <- as.Date(as.character(survey$date), format="%Y/%m/%d")-
                  as.Date(as.character(survey$tx_start), format="%Y/%m/%d")
survey
```

Comment: This comes up with Na's